# Freedos installation on Qemu fails with "unable to locate the installation packages"

Tags: dos, qemu

Trying to install Freedos (v1.2) in Qemu - and it fails always with the same error: `Unable to locate the installation packages.`.

On the web there are versions of the same guide on how to do this: https://opensource.com/article/17/10/run-dos-applications-linux

I can create the image for the hard drive, then run qemu:

```
qemu-system-i386 -m 16 -k en-us -rtc base=localtime -soundhw sb16,adlib -device cirrus-vga -cdrom FD12FULL/FD12FULL.img -hda freedos.img -boot order=d
```

The installation process starts successfully, it finds the hard drive images, then it formats it and mark as primary. Then I can select the language and start the installation - on the next screen it shows a dialogue to gather information about the machine - and the next screen is the failure:

[image]

I've tried the following options when starting qemu:

- for cdrom using the "standard" / "legacy" / "full" / "lite" Freedos installation CD images
- using both these 4 CD images with and without the official Freedos installation Floppy
- booting from CD and booting from Floppy
- attaching the CD img as img or as mounted drive

If I select `No - Return to DOS` I always see 3 drives: (A:) having the CD image, (B:) floppy image, (C:) the empty attached drive image and a (D:) drive which is not readable.

Looked at a few findings in google ([case 1](https://sourceforge.net/p/freedos/bugs/158/), [case 2](https://sourceforge.net/p/freedos/mailman/freedos-user/thread/1d3961fd-080c-cd59-033e-68d2001bce29%40yahoo.com/)) but didn't really helped much.

Answer (score 3):

seems to be a bug in seabios regarding support of ATA CDROMs, see https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/10857581/ and https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=934134

Comment: https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/9367/qemu-emulating-ms-dos-cannot-access-cd-rom?newreg=7e5c9648fb5a4644a2bd227be3bc97ed

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is looking for an answer. The problem was due to a version of seabios that has a CD driver bug. If you download the latest version and compile it. You should be able to provide the "-bios <your_newer_compiled_seabios>" to the qemu command line to get around this problem.

What I did was follow these steps:

```
# Get a newer version of the seabios:
$ git clone https://git.seabios.org/seabios.git
# Change directory and compile it
$ cd seabios
$ make
...
Total size: 185536  Fixed: 87584  Free: 76608 (used 70.8% of 256KiB rom)
  Creating out/bios.bin
```

Then I used the out/bios.bin bios in your qemu command line to load it:

```
$ <your-qemu-command-line> -bios out/bios.bin <any other command options>
```

Hope that helps other folks running into the same problem.